# Get object from array based on property using Lodash _.find

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects, say memberToChange.checkboxes: ICheckbox[] like this:

[image]

Now, I have a variable, say internalNumber: string which has the value "3419". I want to get the object from the array of objects where the internalNumber matches the label property. Ultimately, I want to set the value attribute of that object to true.

My code is:

```
let checkboxes = _.find(scope.selectedMembers, (member: IMember) => member.member.uuid === memberId).checkboxes;     //gives me array of checkboxes.  
let checkboxToChange = _.find(memberToChange.checkboxes, function(checkbox: ICheckbox){
  return (checkbox.label === internalNumber);
}); //gives me null, moreover, even a console.log inside the second find doesn't print. I'm thinking the two consecutive _.find statements are messing something up, not sure what.
```

For reference, this is my ICheckbox interface:

```
export interface ICheckbox {
    label: string;
    sublabel?: string;
    value: boolean;
    numberUuid: string;
}
```

I would expect that for internalNumber 3419, it should return me the second object from the array. But it returns undefined. I'm not sure what's going on here. 
If there is a better way to find and set the value to true in one go only, I'd be happy to know that as well. 
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Update:

After someone suggested using filter method of javascript, I tried this: (my scope is assigned to this)

```
scope.selectedMembers.filter(function(member) {
    if (member.member.uuid === memberId) {
      scope.memberCheckboxes = [];
      console.log('found member'); //prints 
      scope.memberCheckboxes = member.checkboxes;
      console.log(scope.memberCheckboxes); // print correctly, with checkboxes of the member
      scope.memberCheckboxes.filter(function(checkbox) {
        console.log('inside checkbox function'); //control doesnt even come here
        if (checkbox.label === intNum) {
          console.log('found checkbox'); // control doesnt come here 
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Here, I don't understand why the first console.log inside scope.memberCheckboxes.filter doesn't print? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: number !== string?

Comment: Edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: You may have to post a demo to reproduce the issue, all looks fine...

Comment: I created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j8rL780u/27/ with similar values, that worked fine too. That's why I'm baffled why this is not working.

Comment: Why don't you use filter function from array prototype https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter

Comment: I need to see this, haven't used it before.

Comment: @elclanrs I have updated the question with more details of what I observed and another implementation approach. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Please show the exact line where you are setting `internalNumber`. Also, at the top of your screenshot, note carefully where it says `Array[0]`. This indicates that the array is empty. The fact that elements in the array are then being displayed below could be an artifact of the way `console.log` works. It is possible that you are populating `memberToChange.checkboxes`, but then later somehow emptying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By some reason your `memberToChange.checkboxes` (or `member.checkboxes` in your updated question) have no elements.

It is the only explanation why it does not work since your code is otherwise correct. The fact that `console.log('inside checkbox function')` does not print confirms that.

Comment: but when I do console.log(memberToChange.checkboxes), it shows me the expected contents. It's not empty.

Comment: You are right, that's what is happening. But I dont see how it has no elements suddenly when its just printing the values correctly.

Comment: Regarding your first proposal using _.find(), do you somewhere in your real code assign `checkboxes` to `memberToChange.checkboxes`?